# Browser displays raw XML without applying XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformacja2.xsl"?>
<czolgi xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <czolg kraj_pochodzenia="ZSRR" typ="sredni">
        <nazwa>T-34-85</nazwa>
        <zaloga>
            <zalogant>Dowódca</zalogant>
            <zalogant>Kierowca</zalogant>
            <zalogant>Celowniczy</zalogant>
            <zalogant>Ładowniczy</zalogant>
            <zalogant>Strzelec-radiotelegrafista</zalogant>
        </zaloga>
        <uzbrojenie>
            <bron kaliber="85.0"> Armata czołgowa wz. 1944 ZiS-S-53 </bron>
            <bron kaliber="7.62"> 2 Karabiny maszynowe DTM </bron>
        </uzbrojenie>
        <pancerz jednostka="mm">
            <kadlub>45/45/45</kadlub>
            <wieza>90/75/52</wieza>
        </pancerz>
        <info_dodatkowe>
            <silnik moc="500KM">1 silnik wysokoprężny, 12-cylindrowy W-2-34</silnik>
            <rok_wprowadzenia>1944</rok_wprowadzenia>
        </info_dodatkowe>
        <linki>
            <link adres="http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34/85"> Wikipedia PL</link>
            <link adres="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34/85"> Wikipedia EN</link>
        </linki>
    </czolg>
.
.
.
</czolgi>
```

I have a problem transforming this XML file with the following XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Czołgi: Transformacja 2</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Czołgi</h2><br/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="czolgi/czolg">
                <xsl:sort select="info_dodatkowe/rok_wprowadzenia"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="czolg">
    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1"/>. Nazwa: <xsl:value-of select="nazwa"/><br/>
    Kraj pochodzenia: <xsl:value-of select="@kraj_pochodzenia"/>
    Typ:        <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@typ='lekki'">Lekki</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@typ='sredni'">Średni</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@typ='ciezki'">Ciężki</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose><br/>
    Rok wprowadzenia: <xsl:value-of select="info_dodatkowe/rok_wprowadzenia"/><br/>

    <br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's supposed to print something like:
Nazwa: something 
Kraj pochodzenia: something
Typ: something
Rok wprowadzenia: something

for every **czolg** element. But instead, when viewed in a browser, shows raw text from the entire XML file. I can't seem to find the problem on my own. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your sample on http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014011101.xml and it seems to work fine with Firefox, IE and Opera. I am not sure why you don't get the result you want. Check the error console of your browser, make sure it does not show any errors. Also make sure the XML is as posted and does not have some `xmlns="..."` on the root or other elements as then the paths in your XSLT would not select the input elements.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Apparently there was a problem with encoding of special Polish characters. Converting the XSL file to UTF-8 without BOM seemed to solve the problem for me.